# Spring Integration Java DSL Router with Logic

Tags: java, spring-integration

Spring Integration 5.x here, using the Java (not XML) DSL. I have a use case for a `MessageChannel` router with some fairly sophisticated logic, and I'd like to define that logic in Java.

My best attempt thus far is this:

```
public class MyLogicRouter extends AbstractMappingMessageRouter implements RouteConstants {

    private MyLogicRouterService routerService;

    public MyLogicRouter(MyLogicRouterService routerService) {
        this.routerService = routerService;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Object> getChannelKeys(Message<?> message) {

        MessageChannel channel = routingService.determineChannel(message);

        return null; // ???

    }
}
```

But I feel like I'm way off and not using the API correctly at all. At the end of the day, I want to be able to take the headers and payload on a `Message` and route the message to the appropriate `MessageChannel` based on some advanced logic that I want to write/define in the Java layer.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is correct, however you might really not need to extend from `AbstractMappingMessageRouter`. It general it is really enough to mark your `MyLogicRouterService.determineChannel` with a `@Router` or use respective `IntegrationFlow` operator:

```
/**
 * Populate the {@link MethodInvokingRouter} for provided {@link Function}
 * and payload type with default options.
 * Typically, used with a Lambda expression:
 * <pre class="code">
 * {@code
 *  .route(Integer.class, p -> p % 2 == 0)
 * }
 * </pre>
 * @param expectedType the {@link Class} for expected payload type. It can also be
 * {@code Message.class} if you wish to access the entire message in the router.
 * Conversion to this type will be attempted, if necessary.
 * @param router  the {@link Function} to use.
 * @param <S> the source payload type or {@code Message.class}.
 * @param <T> the target result type.
 * @return the current {@link BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition}.
 * @see LambdaMessageProcessor
 */
public <S, T> B route(Class<S> expectedType, Function<S, T> router) {
```

See more info in docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/router.html#router-annotation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-routers